# Best way to add a menu to Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm creating a Grease Monkey script and currently I'm storing my settings variables within the code. But I'd like to make them easily changeable for users. The best way to do it imo is creating a settings menu but I have no idea how to do it and where to start (it's my first browser extention). Can you please explain me what to do (or at least where to look for the info)? 
I'd like to understand:
1) How to store variables and access them?
2) How to put the settings menu in the script?
3) Where can I put this settings menu?

Pseudocode:

```
//settings
let foo = false; // how do
let bar = true;  // I change these guys using the menu?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a container with inputs, and listen for changes to the inputs. On change, save the variables in localStorage. Also, on page load, check to see if the localStorage property has anything in it - if so, populate the inputs with the saved values:

```js
// Retrieve the saved values, or if there aren't any, set the default values
// let vals = localStorage.vals ? JSON.parse(localStorage.vals) : ['3', 'foo', '8'];
let vals = ['3', 'foo', '8'];
const inputs = [...menu.querySelectorAll('input')];

// Populate the inputs with the values:
inputs.forEach((input, i) => input.value = vals[i]);

// Listen for changes to the inputs. On change, put all values into the "vals" variable
// and save it in localStorage:
const menu = document.querySelector('#menu');
menu.addEventListener('input', () => {
  vals = inputs.map(input => input.value);
  console.log(vals);
  // Save it:
  // localStorage.vals = JSON.stringify(vals);
});
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div>var1: <input value="3"></div>
  <div>var2: <input value="foo"></div>
  <div>var3: <input value="8"></div>
</div>
```

(localStorage does not work in the sandboxed Stack Snippet iframe, unfortunately, which is why its use is commented out)

To save an object instead of an array, you might give the inputs names:

```js
// Retrieve the saved values, or if there aren't any, set the default values
// let vals = localStorage.vals ? JSON.parse(localStorage.vals) : { var1: 'foo', var2: 'bar' };
let vals = { var1: 'foo', var2: 'bar' };
const menu = document.querySelector('#menu');
const inputs = [...menu.querySelectorAll('input')];

// Populate the inputs with the values:
Object.entries(vals)
  .forEach(([propName, val]) => {
    menu.querySelector(`input[name="${propName}"]`).value = val;
  });
  
// Listen for changes to the inputs. On change, put all values into the "vals" variable
// and save it in localStorage:
menu.addEventListener('input', () => {
  vals = inputs.reduce((a, input) => {
    a[input.name] = input.value;
    return a;
  }, {});
  console.log(vals);
  // Save it:
  // localStorage.vals = JSON.stringify(vals);
});
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div>var1: <input name="var1"></div>
  <div>var2: <input name="var2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, now I almost understand. But where should I put the <div> to make the menu appear and work?

Comment: Wherever you want - I don't know how you're using the userscript, or where you want the interface to be. Figure out where you want to put it, and then you can insert the `#menu` and run the rest of the script

Comment: ok, let's go step by step:
1) My script looks something like this:
// ==UserScript==
// name         Script
// name:ru      Скрипт
// ==/UserScript==
//Settings
let foo = false;
let bar = true;
//Script itself
ifs-elses function etc etc
I am using the script to color different words on the page. I'd like the menu to appear in tampermonkey menu (after you click plus near the script's name) or by right mb click -->myscriptname --> settings. Or maybe there is some a more convinient place for the menu.
Where should I put the <div>s? And where would you put menu?

Comment: Mistyped, sorry about that

Comment: That's not possible - you'd have to alter Tampermonkey's source code. Put the menu in the *page* instead

Comment: So you're suggesting creating a page specially for the menu and put the menu in this page, right?

Comment: No, put the menu in the page that the script runs on

Comment: But how do I put my divs on the external webpage that's already loaded? Like I go to google.com and then what should I do?

Comment: By using any of the methods which can insert elements, eg ``document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<div>foo</div>`)`` or `appendChild`, or `insertAdjacentElement`, or whatever you want